# how to pre-fill some parts of an access form?

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access

New here, so be gentle with me. - edited to simplify

I'm trying to set up something in Access where:

1. user selects driver name and date
2. query finds stops along the driver's route
3. form opens with route stops (location details) filled in and user can add additional information (item picked up, weight of item)
4. all information gets transferred to a "Pickups" table, which has data on what was picked up, the weight, where (route stop) and by whom (driver).

I have stores A through H, and three drivers, Bob, Tom, and Jill. Bob’s route is stores A,B,C,D. Tom’s route is stores A,C,G,H, and Jill’s route is stores D,E,F,G. (I can't give real names/locations - work is very strict about privacy issues!)

Behind these are “Driver” Table, with driver name, ID, and truck info; and “Store” Table, with store name (A-H), address, phone number, and contact person.

We’re collecting all of the information about items picked up at each store into a “Pickup” table, with Fields: Date, Driver, Store, WeightOfFurniture, WeightOfBooks, WeightOfClothes

The user starts with the driver’s name and date, clicks a button, and this opens a form with the following fields:

Driver, Date, Store, WeightOfFurniture, WeightOfBooks, WeightOfClothes 
with driver and date filled in based on the initial entry, and “Store” having all listings for a given driver’s route. So I select Bob and a date (11-12) and get a form with:

Name    Date    Store   WtFurn      WtBooks WtClothes

Bob     11-12     A

Bob     11-12     B

Bob     11-12     C

Bob     11-12     D

I can get the above information from a query without any problem, but I can't figure out how to (partially) fill the form with the query results (there will be multiple query results for a given route, so DLookup is not useful).

I think recordsets might be a way to go, but not sure how to do this. I'm very new at VBA, but am learning (the hard way!).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell us what tables you have with which fields and give details also on the form contents? Is this supposed to be like a transaction log? Will you have "nothing picked up" rows and do you want them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `INSERT INTO` action query to insert those records into your `Pickup` table.

> I can get the above information from a query without any problem,

This query is the SELECT FROM part for the INSERT query.

Then open your Pickup form, filtered for Driver, Date and Store that you just inserted.